# Django ModelForm - conditional validation

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I need to add a conditional piece of validation to my ModelForm.

Below is my `Listing` Model.

```
LISTING_TYPES = (
    ('event', 'event'),
    ('release', 'release')
)

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Listing Title')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=LISTING_TYPES, verbose_name='Listing Type')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Listing Overview')
    competition = models.TextField()
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    time_start = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()
    time_end = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    date_start = forms.DateField(input_formats=DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    date_end = forms.DateField(input_formats=DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
```

Venue should **only** be required if type == 'event'. If type == 'release', I want venue to be required=False

How can I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First `Listing.venue` needs to allow null values

```
venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True)
```

Your `ModelForm` then needs a [clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#django.forms.Form.clean). Something like the following

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ListingForm, self).clean()
    venue = cleaned_data.get("venue")
    type = cleaned_data.get("type")

    if type == 'event' and not venue:
        raise forms.ValidationError("A venue is required for events")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but could you please explain what you have done? I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned doing `ModelForm` validation, but you should ask yourself if this rule is specific to creating objects with forms, or whether it is inherent in your data model itself. If it's the latter, then doing [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) makes more sense.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        super(Listing, self).clean()

        if self.type == 'event' and not self.venue:
            raise ValidationError('A venue is required for events')
```

This will be called during `ModelForm` validation, so it will have the same effect there, but defining it on the model allows you to check the consistency of your data at any point with the `Model.full_clean()` method.

As Iain points out, you first need to allow null values for `venue`.

```
venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True)
```